# Page indicator using ItemsControl ignores data template

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol

I'm trying to create a page indicator using `ItemsControl`. The idea is to bind to the tabs of a `TabControl` and display a circle for each tab, with the color determined by a trigger that checks whether the tab is selected or not:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=ATabControl}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Ellipse x:Name="PageIndicator" Width="6" Height="6" Margin="2,0" />

      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
          <Setter TargetName="PageIndicator" Property="Fill" Value="White" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="PageIndicator" Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It compiles without error but instead of the circles, I get the names of the tabs listed. Practically, it ignores the `ItemTemplate/DataTemplate` completely. Actually, if I remove the latter, the display remains the same all right.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `DataType={x:Type TabItem}"` from the DataTemplate?

Comment: Yep. Actually, I started without it and added it later but it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: the issue is because you are binding to actual tab items and they are pulled into items control. by the way do you intend it to bind tabcontrol a data source or the tabs are static? I can suggest to use attached properties to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always an issue while binding UI elements in two different containers. as one UI element can have only 1 parent so the last parent will have the actual element and hence the same will be removed from the former parent containers.

in the issue you've mentioned you attempted to bind the UI element TabItems to the items control which effectively pulled the original elements from the tab control and placed them as child of the items control.

in order to solve this issue I propose a solution to wrap such UI elements in a class and wire the properties needed.

I attempted a solution using converter

xaml

```xml
<StackPanel xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <l:TabItemsConverter x:Key="TabItemsConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TabControl x:Name="ATabControl">
        <TabItem Header="item 1" />
        <TabItem Header="item 2" />
        <TabItem Header="item 3" />
    </TabControl>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=ATabControl,Converter={StaticResource TabItemsConverter}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse x:Name="PageIndicator"
                         Width="6"
                         Height="6"
                         Margin="2,0"
                         Fill="Gray" />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                                 Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="PageIndicator"
                                Property="Fill"
                                Value="Gray" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PageIndicator"
                                Property="Fill"
                                Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

converter class

```cs
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class TabItemsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            List<TabItemWrapper> result = new List<TabItemWrapper>();

            foreach (TabItem item in (ItemCollection)value)
            {
                result.Add(new TabItemWrapper(item));
            }
            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        class TabItemWrapper : DependencyObject
        {
            public bool IsSelected
            {
                get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
                set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
            }

            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsSelected.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(TabItemWrapper), new PropertyMetadata(false));

            public TabItemWrapper(TabItem source)
            {
                Binding b = new Binding("IsSelected");
                b.Source = this;
                b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                source.SetBinding(TabItem.IsSelectedProperty, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in this converter I binded the tab item's `IsSelected` to the property of a wrapper class and used it to bind in the view

Note: this converter work for static tab items only, if you intend to add or remove the tab items during runtime then perhaps you may need to handle `CollectionChanged` events to keep the result in sync.

result

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, that was a neat trick. I also tried converters but not this way, wrapping the element, merely to convert from `TabItem` to `Color` or similar but obviously, that suffered from the same problem you mentioned. With this approach, it works just fine, thanks.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you and you liked it. Happy coding :)